# Which Edition of couchbase lite in android?

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite

[link](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads) gives option to download the files needed to run couchDB in android application

But there are two editions

1. Enterprise Edition
2. Community Edition

And i am adding following dependency to build.gradle file of my android application and run it.it downloads necessary files

```
compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.1.0'
```

what i want to know which edition files it downloads

1. Enterprise Edition
2. Community Edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being there is no difference between the Enterprise and Community editions.  Those two downloads are exactly the same binary, or if not only minor packaging differences.  At some point in the future they will probably become different and at that time I'm guessing there will be one gradle ID for each but for now it's not something you need to worry about.

Comment: but i heard about Enterprise edition is for trial basis which could be available for some days later on it will ask for license correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You won't run into problems just by adding the gradle dependency.  If you want the enterprise package it comes with stuff other than the product like premium support (don't quote me on the exact details because I don't work as a product manager or in sales) but you need to enter into a contract for it.

Comment: I figured you were.  Then you don't need to do anything special, just add the gradle dependency.  Unless you ask for the Enterprise package you won't get it.  From a files standpoint, both editions use the same files.

Comment: you talked about gradle ID For each edition can you please tell me in brief about that gradle ID So i can get community edition for sure

Comment: What I said was "At some point in the future."  Right now there is only one ID.

Comment: tnx for giving me  idea about it.

Comment: And just to be clear, Couchbase products that are labeled as Enterprise Editions are for paying customers. So while there may or may not be a difference between the binaries now, there probably will be in the future as the product matures and the license for the Enterprise version is for pay.